# how to change link of some wordpress pages

Tags: functions, pages, hooks, page-template

I've made templates for the pages of my wordpress site such as: singup,signin,suggestions.
Default wordpress pages link is as follows:

`doamin.com/signup/`
or
`doamin.com/signin/`
or
`doamin.com/suggestions/`

I want to just link to this page to be changed as follows:

`doamin.com/panel/signup/`
or
`doamin.com/panel/signin/`
or
`doamin.com/panel/suggestions/`

**Using what code can do this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a **blank page** and name it **panel** then go to your created signup template and select parent page **panel**. Its just below Publish->Page Attributes.

```
/*Add noindex to this page (Add to functions.php)*/
function add_noindex_tags(){
# Add noindex to page.
if( is_page('panel')  )
echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">';
}
add_action('wp_head','add_noindex_tags', 4 );
```

Comment: This blank page will be index in google! How to dont index this page?

Comment: Well try to add code below to your functions.php it should prevent google from indexing...